# Regex - How do you match everything except four digits in a row?

Tags: regex

Using Regex, how do you match everything except four digits in a row? Here is a sample text that I might be using:

```
foo1234bar
baz      1111bat
asdf 0000 fdsa
a123b
```

Matches might look something like the following:

```
"foo", "bar", "baz      ", "bat", "asdf ", " fdsa", "a123b"
```

Here are some regular expressions I've come up with on my own that have failed to capture everything I need:

```
[^\d]+            (this one includes a123b)
^.*(?=[\d]{4})    (this one does not include the line after the 4 digits)
^.*(?=[\d]{4}).*  (this one includes the numbers)
```

Any ideas on how to get matches before and after a four digit sequence?

Comment: What language/regax *flavor* are you using?

Comment: I've just been using http://regexr.com/. My end goal is to substitute a newline for everything that is not a 4 digit number.

Comment: Please see my updated answer, it matches your desired output.

Comment: What `foo 12345 bar` becomes?

Comment: `sample = 'foo 12345 bar'` => `['foo ', ' bar']`

Answer (score 4):

You haven't specified your app language, but practically every app language has a split function, and you'll get what you want if you split on `\d{4}`.

eg in java:

```
String[] stuffToKeep = input.split("\\d{4}");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a negative lookahead:

```
(?!\b\d{4}\b)(\b\w+\b)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dO1hF5/1)

Answer (score 0):

In *Python* the following is very close to what you want:

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: sample = '''foo1234bar
   ...: baz      1111bat
   ...: asdf 0000 fdsa
   ...: a123b'''

In [3]: re.findall(r"([^\d\n]+\d{0,3}[^\d\n]+)", sample)
Out[3]: ['foo', 'bar', 'baz      ', 'bat', 'asdf ', ' fdsa', 'a123b']
```